# Multiple SQL IF statement

Tags: sql, if-statement, concatenation, case, case-statement

So if I got a column like this:

```
Notes   
A, B, C    
A    
A, C    
A, F
```

How do i do a multiple if statements that would look through the column and if it has an A print "cash", if it has a B print "Check", if it has a C print "money order". And concatenate them into one string. Or if a case statement would be better?

Comment: How many distinct values are you checking for, and are they at all likely to change?  And what database are you using?

Comment: And is changing the design an option? CSV in a column is seldom a good idea, probably never if you want to process individual items in SQL.

Comment: There are 7 distinct values and no they are not likely to change. I'm using SQL server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
case when Notes like '%A%' then 'cash' else '' end + 
case when Notes like '%B%' then 'Check' else '' end + 
case when Notes like '%C%' then 'money order' else '' end as 
customstring
from table
```

Comment: How would I go about putting "or" before the last option and commas after each option but not after the last option? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
select replace(replace(replace(Notes,'A','cash'),'C','money order'),'B','Check')
```

or you can use **Case** statement also

Comment: How would I go about putting "or" before the last option and commas after each option but not after the last option? Thanks in advance.